# Is there a canonical inner product for finite dimensional $C^*$-algebras

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

So this might be a fairly basic question, but I can't answer it myself.

A $C^*$-algebra $A$ is a Banach space with additional properties: so a vector space, but without an inner product, only a norm.

If, however, we are only considering the finite-dimensional case, then this algebra $A$ will also be canonically isomorphic (as a vector space) to $\mathbb{C}^n$ for some $n$, via say $\phi:A\xrightarrow{\sim} \mathbb{C}^n$. But on this space, we *do* have an inner product.

Is it therefore sensible (in the following way) to define $\langle x,y\rangle_A\equiv \langle \phi(x),\phi(y) \rangle_{\mathbb{C}^n}$?

Sensible as in: For an operator $T$ on $A$, we can now define the adjoint as usual, $\langle T^*x ,y\rangle = \langle x,Ty\rangle$, and this definition is 'good'

Comment: "A C∗-algebra $A$ is a Banach space with additional properties, but without an inner product, only a norm." What the heck are you talking about?

Comment: Oops, forgot part of the sentence. Should read "A $C^*$-algebra $A$ is a Banach space with additional properties: **so a vector space**, but without inner product, only a norm" Happy now?

Comment: I didn't downvote btw

Comment: Also, my comment was about the fact that that is not what a $C^*$ algebra is. With all due respect, it seems you don't know what a Banach space is or what a $C^*$ algebra is.

Comment: Are you being serious? That is quite literally what a $C^*$ algebra is. It's a Banach algebra with a conjugate linear involution satisfying the $C^*$ identity. And a Banach algebra is a Banach space that is (in a specific sense) an algebra. So in fact a $C^*$ algebra is a Banach space with additional properties. 

Perhaps you just don't like my using of "properties" instead of "structure", but that does not actually cause too much confusion

Comment: sorry, I didn't mean to sound rude

Comment: @user435308 it seems to me that the main reason for objection is that you've classified the "algebraic properties" of the Banach *algebra* as "additional properties". I don't see the big deal though.

Comment: @user435308 It does seem, however, that you're ignoring the multiplication of elements from the $C^*$ algebra.  For instance: we should probably define the inner product in such a way that the adjoint lines up with our involution.  So, if $T_x(y) = xy$, then $T_x^*(y) = yx^*$ (not sure if that's the right way to do it now).

Comment: What do you mean when you say the algebra is canonically isomorphic to $\Bbb C^n$? It is clear that it must be isomorphic to $\Bbb C^n$ as a vector space (this is the definition of finite-dimensional), but there is nothing canonical about this isomorphism.

Comment: Als you probably want $\|a\|^2=(a,a)$ right? I think this condition is impossible, but $\|a\|^2≥(a,a)$ or $\|a\|^2≤(a,a)$ are possible because all norms in finite dimensions are equivalent. I think a canonical construction using pure states is also possible, but right now I don't know if there are only finitely many pure states in a finite dimensional $C^*$ algebra.

Answer (score 1):

These are comments that are unfortunately too long to write as comments. I assume all algebras are unital, but this is not a problem because passing to a unionisation will preserve finite dimensionality.

If your algebra is commutative and finite dimensional then there is a canonical identification of the algebra with $\ell^2(X)=\{f:X\to\Bbb C\}$ where $X$ is a finite set. This is called the Gelfand transform. On $\ell^2(X)$ you have a canonical inner product:
$$(f,g) := \frac1{|X|}\sum_{x\in X}\overline{f(x)}g(x) $$

Now unless $X$ is a single point, ie the algebra is $\Bbb C$, you will not have that the $C^*$ norm is induced by this inner product.

Looking at the non-commutative case, let us be inspired by matrices. Here you have an inner product defined on $M_{n\times n}$ via:
$$(A,B):=\frac{\mathrm{Tr}(A^*B)}{n}$$
This inner product does not induce the same norm as the $C^*$ norm! Now the trace (or better said the *normalised* trace) is something called a state. This is a linear functional $\omega: \mathcal A\to\Bbb C$ so that $\omega(\Bbb1)=1$ and $\omega(P)≥0$ whenever $P$ is positive. Further the normalised trace is *faithful*, this means that if $A>0$ you have $\omega(A)>0$.

If you have a faithful state $\omega$ you automatically get an inner product in the same way, namely via $(a,b):=\omega(a^*b)$. The commutative finite dimensional case is a special case of this, where we have a canonical faithful state via the Gelfand-transform.

The inner products considered here are all compatible with the $C^*$ structure in a certain way. We know that $\mathcal A$ acts linearly on itself via multiplication. So we have an algebra morphism $L:\mathcal A\to B(\mathcal A)$ via $a\mapsto L_a = (b\mapsto a\cdot b)$. Further:
$$(a,L_b c) = \omega(a^*bc)=\omega((b^*a)^*c)=(L_{b^*}a,c) $$
And we verify that this is a $*$-morphism. A non-trivial result is that injective $*$-morphisms are isometries, so here $\mathcal A$ embeds as a sub-algebra of $B(\mathcal A)$. I think this is as good as you can get.

The reason why this is not an answer is that **I don't know if there are canonical faithful states on non-commutative finite dimensional C* algebras**.

Comment: If there is a canonical state, it should be fixed under all automorphisms, which are all inner: that does not leave a lot of wiggle room!

Comment: Every finite dimensional $C^*$ algebra embeds into some matrix algebra right? There the normalised trace does the job, and restricting it to the original algebra will keep it invariant under inner automorphisms. So there exist states with this property, but unless we have a canonical embedding this doesn't help in picking a special one out. I think the GNS representation is generally into an infinite dimensional Hilbert space, because you are summing over all pure states.

Comment: Every finite dimensional algebra embdes in a matrix algebra, no need of the C^*.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I have thought about this again and written an answer. The argument seems pretty simple, and I was wondering if the construction is often used (if it is not wrong) :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I came back to this question and I think I have an answer. I'm posting this separately to my "long comment". In the comment I motivated that one needs to canonically construct a faithful state that is invariant under inner automorphisms.

The unitaries $U(\mathcal A)\subset \mathcal A$ are a compact topological group and thus you have a canonical positive measure of mass $1$ on them. Lets call this measure $du$. If we have any state $\omega$ of $\mathcal A$, we can make this state invariant  under inner automorphisms by taking the mean over $U(\mathcal A)$:
$$\omega'(a):=\int_{U(\mathcal A)}\omega(uau^*)\ du$$
This averaging will preserve the faithfullness of $\omega$. Where can we find a canonical state over which we take the mean? Well we can just take the mean over all states. Faithful states are a bounded convex subset of the finite dimensional $\mathcal A'$, such sets also have probability measures on them (take the Lebesgue measure on the real vector space generated by the set and normalise so that the set has volume $1$). So we can just take the mean over all states:
$$\omega(a):=\int_{\text{Faithful states of }\mathcal A}\nu(a)\,d\nu$$

As described in the comment a faithful state that is invariant under inner automorphisms induces a Hilbert space structure on $\mathcal A$, if we call this Hilbert space $H_\mathcal A$ then the map
$$L: \mathcal A\to B(H_\mathcal A), a\mapsto (x\mapsto a\cdot x)$$
is an isometric $*$-morphism.